# sqlserver PDO query error

Tags: php, pdo, sql-server-2014

I have this query to be executed:

```
try {
      $dbh = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=database','user','pass');
} catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
}     
      $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $checkQuery = "SELECT `userName` FROM `user_Status` WHERE `userName` = :userName";
      $prepared = $dbh->prepare($checkQuery);
      $prepared->bindValue(':userName', $_POST['username']);
      $prepared->execute();
      $count = $prepared->rowCount();
```

I am getting an error when executing this query and I have spent 3-4 hours searching for similar errors and scanning my code trying to find it but I just can't find it. I figure maybe some other sets of eyes may point it out or maybe I am just doing something completely wrong and don't realize it. Here is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '`'.' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\InOutBoard\authorize.php:68 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\InOutBoard\authorize.php(68): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\InOutBoard\authorize.php on line 68

Line 68 is the execute statement, but I don't see any problem with that and I don't see where it is getting the incorrect syntax error near '`'.'` as I can't find any any in my code nor anything I would see to cause an error, I don't think I'm using any reserved words either. I used to have  "SELECT `userName` FROM `Database.user_Status` but I even tried removing that and nothing changed. I am sure I have the right Database, user and password as well as table. Any help?

Comment: have you tried putting directly the request in your sgbd ?

Comment: You sure backticks are for sql server ? I think it's for mysql, for sql double quotes, or single quote I think. Let me check first.

Comment: I removed the backticks and it ran the query, only weird thing is $count is -1, is that normal? The row it is checking for should exist but is -1 really what I should expect? Shouldn't it be 1?

EDIT:

I used a fetchAll and ran through the result and it is grabbing all the proper values so should I be concerned with the -1 value?

Comment: Might be of interest to you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628154(v=sql.105).aspx .. "*If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, a PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY cursor returns -1. A PDO::CURSOR_SCROLLABLE cursor returns the number of rows in the result set.*"

Comment: For sql server, square brackets if you use reserved words as column. If you look at the manual for `rowCount`, the behaviour is not guaranteed for `SELECT` statement, but you can fetch all the result and count it in `PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @frz3993 and Marcus for the help. I fixed the problem by removing the backticks as I was used to using them for mySQL but forgot that I was not in need of them for mssq